# Extract a word from a string in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a string as
$sea = xyz-ajay-no-siddhart-ubidone-fdh-DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1.tgz

and i want to extract only DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1 and search string will be DMJK

I tried like

```
echo $sea
y=${sea/\/*\//};
echo ${y/.*/};
```

but its not working, please help

Answer (score 1):

How you want to choose what to remove and what to keep is not at all clear.  This is one of many ways to get the result that you ask for:

```
$ sea=xyz-ajay-no-siddhart-ubidone-fdh-DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1.tgz
$ sea2=${sea/*[[:lower:]]-/}; echo ${sea2%.*}
DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1
```

Alternatively, this includes the parts starting with `DMJK` and leaving off the final `.tgz`:

```
$ sea2=${sea/*DMJK/DMJK}; echo ${sea2%.tgz}
DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1
```

This same approach works even if the `.tgz` is not present:

```
$ sea=xyz-ajay-no-siddhart-ubidone-fdh-DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1
$ sea2=${sea/*DMJK/DMJK}; echo ${sea2%.tgz}
DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, 
I have to choose from DMJK to .tgz

Comment: @AjayGautam OK.  I added a solution that removes everything before `DMJK` and also removes the final `.tgz`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, i am very new for regular expressionand , 

how to extract only DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1 
xyz-ajay-no-siddhart-ubidone-fdh-DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1
again for this i have to search DMJK and 
xyz-ajay-no-siddhart-ubidone-fdh-DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1 may be folder

Comment: @AjayGautam OK.  I updated the answer to add that example.

Comment: is it possible to combine these 2 statements in 1 and assign in a veriable e.g.

sea2=${${sea/*DMJK/DMJK}%.tgz}
I tried, but its not working.

Comment: @AjayGautam No, shell is not that flexible: it needs two statements.

Answer (score 0):

How are you determining which characters to extract? If the characters always appear in specific places in the string, e.g. if its a fixed length string or the characters you need are the last 21 characters before a dot and 3 character extension, you could use one of the following in a Bash script:

```
sea="xyz-ajay-no-siddhart-ubidone-fdh-DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1.tgz"

echo $sea
# If characters are always in positions 33 to 50
y=${sea:33:21}
echo $y

# If y always start 5 positions from the end and goes back 21 characters
# For negative numbers you need to put a space between the colon and the
# number
#
# Get the last 25 characters in the string
y=${sea: -25}
# Now discard the last 4, which are the dot and 3 character extension
y=${y:0:21}
echo $y
```

Comment: No positions are not fixed

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the way your variable may look in other instances.

It could be as simple as:

```
echo $sea | cut -d '-' -f 7- | cut -d . -f -4
```

or

```
echo $sea | sed 's#.*\(DMJK.*\).tgz#\1#g'
```

Comment: Little modification in question: $sea = xyz-ajay-no-siddhart-ubidone-fdh-DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1.tgz matchessadds.dsdsds.21212 or $sea = xyz-ajay-no-siddhart-ubidone-fdh-DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1.tar.bz2 matchessadds.dsdsds.21212,                                                            
need to extract start from DMJK and before either ".tgz" or ".tar", 
I tried echo $sea | sed 's#.*\(DMJK.*\).t*#\1#g' , but failed
o/p should be DMJK.UK.1.0-32133-Z-1 in the above case.
String can change on fly, so o/p should be DMJK.UK.1.3.0-3213309-Z-13

Comment: so o/p should be DMJK.UK.1.3.0-3213309-Z-13, no other thing